# How to make specific dimens for Nexus 10 and Nexus 9

Tags: android, android-layout, nexus-10

Nexus 9 has different aspect ratio, so the layout looks ugly when using 10" dimens.

I created two folders: `values-sw768dp-port`for Nexus 9 and `values-sw720dp-port` for Nexus 10. But it doesn't work, Nexus 10 takes the dimens from `sw768dp` folder.

Please advice how to make specific dimens for Nexus 10 and Nexus 9. Thanks

Comment: I wrote a long and detailed answer to your question about a perspective camera in libgdx, only to see that the question was deleted. Are you still interested in the solution? It's an elegant one. :)

Comment: @Tenfour04, Hi. I found another way to do so, but would like to see your solution with pleasure :)

Comment: Can you undelete the question? It would be helpful for others to see your solution too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that the Nexus 10 has a sw (smallest width) value of `800dp`, so it is taking the best fit, which is `sw768dp`. Try moving the Nexus 10 content into a folder for `sw800dp`.

The Nexus 9 will continue to take its cues from the `sw768dp` folder